# Format text from JSON object(server response)

Tags: jquery, json

I am making a POST to the server, which returns an object.

The object is JSON and looks like this;

```
Object {yourVote: 7, totalVotes: 41, average: "6.9"}
```

I want to get the text and values from this object and use them in my html - give them classes, color, etc.

How would i go about achieving that?

So far, i have tried fetching the text of the object using .txt() but that returns an error of undefined. I have also tried converting that JSON object to an array so i can access its values that way but, alas, that returns an error again.

Here is my code:

My AJAX request:

```
 $.ajax({
            dataType: "JSON",
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/phometervote",
            data: {
                articleId: articleId,
                vote: userVote
            },
            success: function (rn) {

                var message = rn,
                    messageContent = message.makeArray();

                // I would like to be able to access the object as an array
                //So that way i can access each item individually
                //This returns an error
                $(".someClass").html(messageContent[0]);

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access each field using the response object, try this way:

```
  $.ajax({
        dataType: "JSON",
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/phometervote",
        data: {
            articleId: articleId,
            vote: userVote
        },
        success: function (response) {

            $(".someClass").html(response.yourVote);
            $(".someClass1").html(response.totalVotes);
            $(".someClass2").html(response.average);

        }

    });
```